# Trouble downloading xlsx file from website - Scraping

Tags: python, vba, xpath, import, web-scraping

I'm trying to write some code which download the two latest publications of the Outage Weeks found at the  bottom of http://www.eirgridgroup.com/customer-and-industry/general-customer-information/outage-information/

It's xlsx-files, which I'm going to load into Excel afterwards.
It doesn't matter which programming language the code is written in.

My first idea was to use the direct url's, like http://www.eirgridgroup.com/site-files/library/EirGrid/Outage-Weeks_36(2016)-51(2016)_31%20August.xlsx
, and then make some code which guesses the url of the two latest publications.
But I have noticed some inconsistencies in the url names, so that solution wouldn't work.

Instead it might be solution to scrape the website and use the XPath to download the files. I found out that the two latest publications always have the following XPaths:

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/p[5]/a
/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/p[6]/a
```

This is where I need help. I'm new to both XPath and Web Scraping. I have tried stuff like this in Python

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('http://www.eirgridgroup.com/customer-and-industry/general-customer-information/outage-information/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

v = tree.xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/p[5]/a')
```

But v seems to be empty.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use *contains* to find the *hrefs* and slice the first two:

```
 tree.xpath('//p/a[contains(@href, "/site-files/library/EirGrid/Outage-Weeks")]/@href')[:2]
```

Or doing it all with the xpath using `[position() < 3]`:

```
tree.xpath'(//p/a[contains(@href, "site-files/library/EirGrid/Outage-Weeks")])[position() < 3]/@href')
```

The files are ordered from latest to oldest so getting the first two gives you the two newest.

To download the files you just need to join each href to the base url and write the content to a file:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import os
from urlparse import urljoin # from urllib.parse import urljoin


page = requests.get('http://www.eirgridgroup.com/customer-and-industry/general-customer-information/outage-information/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

v = tree.xpath('(//p/a[contains(@href, "/site-files/library/EirGrid/Outage-Weeks")])[position() < 3]/@href')
for href in v:
    # os.path.basename(href) -> Outage-Weeks_35(2016)-50(2016).xlsx 
    with open(os.path.basename(href), "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(urljoin("http://www.eirgridgroup.com", link)).content)
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much @PadraicCunningham ! I really didn't have a clue. :) Now just one last question. How do I store the two xlsx files, which is now stored in v?

Comment: @JSkjold, do you mean download?

Comment: Yes, @PadraicCunningham. But never mind, I figured it out. But thanks again! Cheers

Comment: No prob, the second snippet does it anyway.